# Difference between fatal error and non-fatal error

Tags: c++

What is the main difference between fatal errors and non-fatal errors dipslayed in an IDE when one tries to compile the code?

In both cases the compiler shows an error message and the program is not compiled. Are fatal errors the undefined compiler errors in a compiler or linker?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25402049/6313992

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IDE is not the compiler. It generally starts another program (like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) in command line to compile. Your IDE is simply a glorified editor (and on Linux the `emacs` editor is often better than an IDE).

Most compilers don't give fatal errors, except on compiler bugs, lacking resources at compile time, or when the source input cannot be further compiled: think of `#include`-ing a non existent header file.

BTW, sometimes a compiler gives so many errors (for instance, try to compile an English or French literature text disguised as a C file) that further compilation is meaning less.

Comment: I know the the error is from compiler. btw, it is displayed in the IDE.

Comment: Try another compiler, like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) using `gcc -Wall -g` on the command line.

Answer (score 9):

A *fatal error* would probably stop compilation of that translation unit immediately.

A compiler may continue compiling after an *error* in order to reveal to you a more comprehensive list of issues.

Although in your case it appears that the *preprocessor* has issued the *fatal error*. Perhaps it's simply down to the mood of the compiler writer.

Answer (score 7):

The difference is this:

- on a normal error, the compiler can continue its parsing, it's just a local problem (undeclared variable for instance, but the compiler knows how to recover from it. Some compilers go far in that process, adding missing `;` and such)
- on a fatal error, the compiler (or preprocessor) cannot possibly know how to continue (like it's "lost") because of a structural error (loses the context)

Which explains that sometimes you fix all your compiling errors, and new ones appear.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is usually based on a compilation unit (a single `.cpp` file) although sometimes on the entire build process.

The main difference is that a fatal error will cause it to give up compiling. So for example if you get a fatal error through including a header that doesn't exist, it will not compile the compilation unit.

If you get a regular error, e.g. use an undefined symbol or miss a closing parenthesis, it will try to compile the rest of the file for you. This might find further errors which you can then fix in one go before trying to recompile. Of course some of these might be caused by the previous one.

There is no "standard" as such, a missing header might be considered "fatal" because it is very likely that without the header there will be loads of undefined types etc. later on so it is considered "not worth" reporting them. A different compiler could decide that error is not fatal and just report them all anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A logic error (e.g., when both braces in a block are left out) has its effect at execution time.
A fatal logic error causes an app to fail and terminate prematurely.
A nonfatal logic error allows an app to continue executing, but causes it to produce incorrect results.

Comment: As the question is related to *IDE's build / compile errors* and in regard of the already existing answers to this question, it seems that your answer is too generalized and doesn't  bring new / distinct points. I suggest you then to revise your answer.